# Averaging multiple xarray DataArrays results in no data, errors, or wrong answer

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to average multiple Xarray DataArrays but the result I get is wrong. The data are not aligned along the time dimension, but I want to average each array with the each time step across the arrays being averaged, no matter what the time coordinate is.

One of my xarrays is the following :

```py
Dimensions:
time: 9125, bnds: 2, lat: 160, lon: 320
Coordinates:
time   (time)    object    1975-01-01 12:00:00 ... 1999-12-...
lat    (lat)     float64   -89.14 -88.03 ... 88.03 89.14
lon    (lon)     float64   0.0 1.125 2.25 ... 357.8 358.9
height ()        float64   ...
Data variables:
time_bnds    (time, bnds)   object    ...
lat_bnds     (lat, bnds)    float64   ...
lon_bnds     (lon, bnds)    float64   ...
tas.      (time, lat, lon). float32.  ...
```

and my second Xarray is the following :

```py
time.     (time)     object    2065-01-01 12:00:00 ...208912-...
lat       (lat)      float64   -89.14 -88.03 ... 88.03 89.14
lon       (lon)      float64.  0.0 1.125 2.25 ... 357.8 358.9
height.   ()         float64   ...
Data variables:
time_bnds.  (time, bnds).       object   ...
lat_bnds.   (lat, bnds)         float64. ...
lon_bnds.   (lon, bnds).        float64. ...
tas.        (time, lat, lon).   float32. ...
```

However, I am not really interested if the data is aligned on the time coordinate. I just wish to find the mean of the variable temperature and create a new Xarray with the mean.  All my xarrays have the same 3 dimensions `(time, lat,lon)` with the same size `(9125,160,320)`

Comment: Hi there - welcome to stack overflow! Please see the guide to [ask]. There are a good number of questions out there asking how to average data in xarray - do any of them help? Also check out the xarray [getting started guide](https://xarray-spatial.org/getting_started/index.html). If none of that answers your question, you'll need to be more clear about what it is that you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what's not working. See this guide to creating a [mre]. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Micheal. Thank you for your feedback. I will update the question again to make it more clear perhaps. I tried to find an answer but most of the questions were related on how to average temperature for example from a single Xarray. What I want is to create a new Xarray which contains the average of 3 other xarrays along the dimension of time

Comment: yep, and without knowing what your data looks like it's hard to tell why `(a + b + c) / 3` doesn't work :). please read the guide to creating a [mre] carefully. printing your data and posting it would be a helpful start.

Comment: Hey Michael! Thank you very much for the immediate response. I will update the question with information of my xarray. I am sorry but I am quite new to python and in coding in general and did not know how to formulate my question better!

Comment: no worries - thanks for being open to feedback!

Comment: we'd actually need to see all of the arrays. what I'm guessing is that your arrays might not be perfectly aligned. see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866469/subtract-two-xarrays-while-keeping-all-dimensions/69867005#69867005

Comment: Hey @MichaelDelgado indeed I used the command xr.align(bcc_csm2_historical, bcc_csm2_ssp126, join='exact')and I got the following error : ValueError: indexes along dimension 'time' are not equal. I tried the following bcc_csm2_ssp126['time'] = np.round(bcc_csm2_ssp126['time'], 3) but I got the following error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'cftime._cftime.DatetimeNoLeap' and 'float'

Comment: got it. it looks like you're trying to take the element-wise mean of the two arrays, ***ignoring the labels in the time dimension***, but simply aligning on the fact that the time dimensions are both 9125 long. Is that right?

Comment: Hey @MichaelDelgado yes I just want to add them. However, when I tried the command as you can see on the main post it did not work properly

Comment: thanks for all the edits - I hope my answer helps! In the interest of making this question useful to others with a similar problem, can you try to clarify and simplify your question? Please do not include multiple Edit: blocks in your question - instead, just edit the question to provide all the necessary information. Additionally, please post the actual text output of print(ds) rather than a picture. On stack overflow, it is requested that you [please do not post images of code, data, or errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - instead, use formatted code blocks. Thanks!

Comment: I also just edited the question name to help others find it, and dropped the netCDF tags (I know it's a netCDF data but this problem itself is specific to xarray)

Comment: Hey @MichaelDelgado thank you very much for all the input! I will re edit the whole question according to the guidelines you provided me! You were really helpful and insightful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind xarray is that it pairs the features of an N-dimensional array computing model such as numpy or dask.array with the labels-based indexing of pandas. Xarray places a huge amount of importance on the concepts of dimension names and coordinate lables, and I highly recommend checking out the xarray docs on [computation using coordinates](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#computation-using-coordinates) and also [automatic alignment](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#automatic-alignment) before diving in any further.

As a concrete example, just as adding two pandas series with mismatched indices would not work:

```py
In [23]: pd.Series([1, 2], index=[1, 2]) + pd.Series([3, 4], index=[3, 4])
Out[23]:
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
dtype: float64
```

you cannot add two xarray DataArrays together with mis-aligned coordinates without aligning them somehow:

```py
In [26]: (
    ...:     xr.DataArray([1, 2], dims=['x'], coords=[[1, 2]])
    ...:     + xr.DataArray([3, 4], dims=['x'], coords=[[3, 4]])
    ...: )
Out[26]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 0)>
array([], dtype=int64)
Coordinates:
  * x        (x) int64
```

So in your case, trying to do an element-wise mean across multiple arrays with similar shapes but mismatched labels along the time dimension, you have a couple options:

1. don't use xarray

   really, what you're trying to do is to treat your DataArrays like they are numpy arrays. You know what's really great at behaving like numpy? Numpy! :) You can access the arrays underlying any DataArray using the `.data` attribute:

   ```py
   mean = (x1['tas'].data + x2['tas'].data + x3['tas'].data) / 3
   ```
2. change your time dimension to a positional index

   another option is replacing your time dim with something that *is* aligned across the arrays. One easy way to do this would be to drop the time dimension entirely, using [`da.reset_index('time')`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/generated/xarray.DataArray.reset_index.html):

   ```py
   mean = (
       x1['tas'].reset_index('time')
       + x2['tas'].reset_index('time')
       + x3['tas'].reset_index('time')
   ) / 3
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you want to achieve. So you'd like to take the temporal mean over all 3 xarrays, resulting in an xarray that just has the dimensions 'latitude' and 'longitude'?

Then I'd suggest concatenating the Dataarrays along the dimension 'time' using `concat` and simply applying the `mean` function:

Example:

```
import xarray as xr

#create some test data
#store 3 dataarrays with random data of shape (time,lat,lon) in a list
data=[]
for i in range(3):
    x=np.random.random((100,10,10))
    data.append(xr.DataArray(x,dims=('time','lat','lon')))

#concatenate along time dimension
data_concat=xr.concat(data,dim='time')
#compute mean
data_concat.mean('time')
```

Comment: Hey Mathi. Thank you for the reply. Yes I want to create a new Xarray that the values that it has for the temperature variable are the mean of the temperature values of the other 3 xarrays for along the dimension time. If I understood correctly from your input I should do the following : assume x1,x2,x3 are the 3 xarrays then temp1 = xr.concat([x1,x2],dim='time'], temp2 = xr.concat([temp1,x3],dim='time'] and then just temp2.mean('time')

Comment: I think just `xr.concat([x1, x2, x3], dim='time').mean(dim='time')`

Comment: What @MichaelDelgado wrote. Else you give more weight to x3 than to x1 and x2. To get started with xarray I recommend doing one of the tutorials, it's really easy: https://xarray-contrib.github.io/xarray-tutorial/