# Masking using Xarray.where throws an error "dimension 'y' are not equal"

Tags: python, raster, python-xarray, rasterio

I am trying to mask a raster using another raster. Both rasters have same dimensions, but when i apply the mask  the xarraydata.where throws error

```
f[0].where(mask,other=np.nan)
```

ValueError: indexes along dimension 'y' are not equal

[image: mask]

[image: 2]

Comment: Check out this question - I think you likely have a very similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866469/subtract-two-xarrays-while-keeping-all-dimensions/69867005#69867005.

Comment: In terms of your question though, please see this guide to creating a [mre] ([this guide](http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports) is also helpful). When asking about errors, please always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback). And [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - instead at least paste the result of `print(ds)` or better yet create an example in code.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same problem for a few hours due to a lack of helpful answers online.

This line:

`self.file[var] = self.file[var].where(self.not_rectangle, other=val)`

was giving an error similar to yours:

`indexes along dimension 'lsmlat' are not equal`

**I solved it by adding the extension .data** in my definition of self.rectangle:

`self.rectangle = self._landmask_file.landmask_diff.data`

I hope this helps!