# xarray multiplication is creating incorrect output shape

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication, python-xarray

I am doing a multiplication of two xarrays in python such as follows:

`z = x * y` where `x` and `y` are xarrays with dimensions `[30,33,720,1440]` for `x` and `[33,720,1440]` for `y`. The coordinates along dimensions 1, 2 and 3 for x match the coordinates along dimensions 0, 1 and 2 for y, and have the same dimension names (pressure, latitude, longitude). Strangely, the output, `z` has dimensions `[30,33,630,1237]`.

I have figured out this is caused by one of the latitude arrays differing from the other by an extremely small amount, `-1.42108547e-14`, at 90 points, which is practically the no difference. A similar thing happens for the longitude. Any ideas on how to eliminate this difference or force xarray to ignore it? (I'd rather not do the multiplication with numpy).

In case you are wondering, I did try

`x.assign_coords(lat=y.lat,lon=y.lon)`

I don't know why that didn't work. Maybe its because one coordinate array has a different type (float32 vs float64)?

Comment: What did you expect that to do?  You've given it two mismatched arrays.  They do NOT have the same shape in dimensions 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: I shouldn't have been so snarky.  `numpy` does that operation just fine, presumably broadcasting `y` to match `x`.  Hard to me to imagine why xarray would do part of the operation then stop.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have good reasons for sticking with xarray, but the details would be unnecessary to include. Yes, they don't have the same shape, but xarray doesn't care. I misspoke and should have phrased; they have the same dims for pressure, lat lon, which is dims 1, 2 and 3 for x and 0, 1, 2 for y (corrected now). If the dimensions are named, then xarray does the broadcasting automatically. Saves a ton of effort.

Comment: Assign coords is not an in-place operation. Everything would work with `x = x.assign_coords(lat=y.lat,lon=y.lon)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subtract two xarrays while keeping all dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866469/subtract-two-xarrays-while-keeping-all-dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
y_new = x[0,:,:,:].copy()
y_new.values = y.values
z = x * y_new
```

Comment: That's multiplying `x` by part of itself.  Is that what you wanted?  That gets rid of whatever was in `y` before.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).